# How can I simulate a bounce in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, canvas, physics

I am trying to cause a rectangle to fall with gravity, bounce when it hits the bottom of my canvas, and after several bounces come to a stop.

With the code below, my rectangle will launch with extra force after hitting the bottom of the canvas. After setting acceleration to zero, I determined that it is something wrong with the velocity portion of my equation.

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

// System settings
var restitution = -0.7;
var a = -32/Math.pow(1000,2); // acceleration

var myRectangle = {};

var draw = {
    rectangle: function (x, y, width, height) {
        context.beginPath();
        context.rect(x, y, height, width);
        context.fillStyle = '#8ED6FF';
        context.fill();
        context.lineWidth = 5;
        context.strokeStyle = 'black';
        context.stroke();
    }
};

function init() {
    myRectangle = {
        width   : 100,
        height  : 100,
        p_0     : {x:canvas.width/2, y:canvas.height/2},
        p       : {x:canvas.width/2, y:canvas.height/2},
        v_0     : {x:0, y:0},
        v       : {x:0, y:0},
        t_0     : (new Date()).getTime(),
        t       : 0
    };
    animate();
}

function animate() {

    // Bounce on the bottom
    if (    (myRectangle.p.y <= myRectangle.height)
        &&  (myRectangle.v.y < 0)){

        // Create new initial conditions on bounce
        myRectangle.p.y = myRectangle.height;
        myRectangle.p_0 = myRectangle.p;
        myRectangle.v_0.y = restitution * myRectangle.v.y;
        myRectangle.t_0 = (new Date()).getTime();
    }

    // Update rectangle time and position
    myRectangle.t = ((new Date()).getTime() - myRectangle.t_0);
    myRectangle.v.y = a*myRectangle.t + myRectangle.v_0.y;
    myRectangle.p.y = a*Math.pow(myRectangle.t,2)/2 + myRectangle.v_0.y * myRectangle.t + myRectangle.p_0.y;

    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    draw.rectangle(myRectangle.p.x, canvas.height-myRectangle.p.y, myRectangle.width, myRectangle.height);

    window.requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}
```

Comment: If your problem was caused by what amounts to a typo, then you should delete your question.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that it was actually an error with the initial position portion of the equation. I cannot simply set an object equal to another object but instead have to copy of its properties individually. Solution is below:

```
// Bounce on the bottom
    if (    (myRectangle.p.y <= myRectangle.height)
        &&  (myRectangle.v.y < 0)){
        // Create new initial conditions on bounce
        myRectangle.p.y = myRectangle.height;

        // THIS LINE WAS INCORRECT
        myRectangle.p_0.y = myRectangle.p.y;

        myRectangle.v_0.y = restitution * myRectangle.v.y;
        myRectangle.t_0 = (new Date()).getTime();
    }
```